# Using Talend ETL tool, How to insert a non existing record to MySQL table from Excel Sheet?

Tags: mysql, talend

I have an excel sheet column in which I need to insert only non existing records.
Example: list of university 
1. Sri Krishnadevaraya University 
2. Sri Krishnadeveraya University(SKU) 
3. St Jerome University 
4. St.Peters University

table already have "St.Peters University" 
so I need to insert 
1. Sri Krishnadevaraya University 
2. Sri Krishnadeveraya University(SKU) 
3. St Jerome University.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in talend you would use the components tfileinput-->tlogrow-->tmap--tlogrow-tmysqloutput. Any filter / transformations / business logic can be done in the tmap component.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    *
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    *
        WHERE   * = *
        )
```

**Not too familiar with Talend but this post is quite useful :**

*[Talend Insert where not exists](https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/How-to-only-insert-record-which-is-not-exist-in-database/td-p/24257)*

Comment: using talend, i need to insert. I'm automating the job.

Comment: You never said / asked for talend

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17746795)

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida The original answer was a good answer, because he had not mentioned talend before. I am not even close to being familiar with talend so I tried editing my answer so i could atleast provide him some extra  help

Answer (score 1):

If you write to MySQL, you are using the tMySQLOutput component - I am only assuming here because there are no information about the job layout whatsoever.

Since MySQL has a feature called *insert ignore*, you should focus on

- setting a good valid primary key (Ignore checks if the PK exists)
- setting the insert strategy to *insert ignore* in the component

Comment: i'm importing from excel sheet to mysql. so i can't use mysql features, all i can do either in talend etl tool or excel sheet.

Comment: What? That makes no sense to me. I am talking exactly about the "to mysql" part in Talend ETL tool. Please show your job layout.

Comment: now how i can make sure that i'm inserting non existing universities to mysql database from excel sheet using talend.

Comment: Again, please see the settings of the MYSQL output and check setting a good primary key in the table.